# multiple fields searching

Tags: c#, database

I am going to develop C# form based desktop application in which i am developing a searching module. Search criteria is if the field is empty, leave it and if the two or more than two fields are filled that search result will display by AND all fields. I am unable to make query for this. please help me
Regards

Comment: I am using sql server and in the query id = "" gives error so one solution is i have to write multiple queries and on the basis of if n else i will decide what query will execute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A typical approach here would be:

```
var query = new StringBuilder();
query.Append("select ... From ... Where 1=1");
if(fooHasValue) {
    query.Append(" and Foo = @foo");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("foo", foo);
}
if(barHasValue) {
    query.Append(" and Bar = @bar");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("bar", bar);
}
cmd.CommandText = query.ToString();
```

Or something similar.

I using LINQ;

```
IQueryable<Whatever> query = ctx.TheTable;
if(fooHasValue)
    query = query.Where(x => x.Foo == foo);
if(barHasValue)
    query = query.Where(x => x.Bar == bar);
foreach(var row in query) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, in order to count the non-null columns (c1 ... c4):

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE
  (CASE WHEN c1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
  CASE WHEN c2 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
  CASE WHEN c3 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END + 
  CASE WHEN c4 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) >= 2
```